# Is there a way to automatically skip the intro videos in Left 4 Dead?

Tags: pc, left-4-dead

Every time you start Left 4 Dead, it plays a short video to introduce Valve software, then it plays the game intro video.  You can skip these videos by pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> twice, but is there an easier way to do this automatically?

Comment: I actually quite like the game intro videos :P

Comment: That's the best part of the game!

Comment: @Macha @JohnFx It is an amazing video, for many reasons, but after watching it for the hundredth time I can now see it in my head.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Right-click the game's entry in your library, click "Properties", "Set Launch Options..." and add
`-novid`. That'll automatically skip all the videos.

By the way, this goes for any Source game.

Comment: That is brilliant. Is there something equally convenient for non-source steam games?