# How do I automatically skip the valve loading movie on Steam/TF2?

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2, half-life-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to automatically skip the intro videos in Left 4 Dead?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2151/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-skip-the-intro-videos-in-left-4-dead)

Each time I open TF2 I see the wonderful valve loading movie, I remember there was an option of --novideo for HL1 which used to remove it.

Any similar command line / preference I can use to disable it for Steam / TF2?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use "-novid" in for any Source game. To add it, right click on game and select properties. Then "Set Launch Options" and type in "-novid". This will skip the launch video.

Comment: Is there a list of all Launch Options for Steam games anywhere?

Comment: Here you go http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Launch_options#Source_Games

Comment: Will these options sync between Steam installs / machines?

Comment: I don't believe so